# mathjax in shiny suddenly stopped working

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app running on AWS with Ubuntu. It uses mathjax and has been running perfectly for several weeks. Today it just stopped rendering the mathjax code. I did not make any changes to the system or the code. When I test the app locally I have the same issue. Anyone had similar problems?

[http://ec2-54-76-89-164.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3838/Quizii Rekentoets](http://ec2-54-76-89-164.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3838/Quizii%20Rekentoets)

Comment: This is a known issue see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/Vsnlv8XR_9o . Install the dev version of shiny `devtool::install_github("rstudio/shiny")` should contain a fix.

Comment: this will presumably be superseded in a few weeks once all the updated package versions etc. roll out, but it's a useful link in the meantime ...

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I did see the proposed fix but when I tried it, it produced an error message: "Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.2.4 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.6 is required" I checked for the newest version of htmltools and could not find a version above 0.2.4.

Comment: It's funny though: I built the app for my students during the holidays. The semester starts Monday and on Sunday the darn thing decides to quit after weeks of working impeccably! I suppose I'll have to wait. Maybe it'll start working again when the holidays arrive ;-)

Comment: I solved the issue with htmltools. I needed to uninstall 0.2.4 and then install 0.2.6 via the github version. Everything seems to be working again (locally and AWS).

Comment: FYI, htmltools 0.2.6 is on CRAN now.