# MathJax Zoom.js issue Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I see in 2014 [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705703/mathjax-in-shiny-suddenly-stopped-working) also had the problem that MathJaxzoom.js stopped working in R's Shiny app. It gives the following error:

```
File failed to load: http://127.0.0.1:4299/file1a9839f31451_files/mathjax-local/extensions/MathZoom.js
```

I now get the same problem - is it still a persistent problem? It worked this morning and just randomly stopped doing so now.

Any ideas on how to fix this or why it failed to work?

Session info:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
RStudio Version 0.99.876
leaflet_1.0.0        tidyr_0.4.0         
dplyr_0.4.3          lubridate_1.5.0     RevoUtilsMath_3.2.3
htmltools_0.3        shiny_0.13.0        plotly 2.0.16
```

Comment: Is the file at the location the localhost is trying to access? Is it elsewhere?

Comment: Not sure how Rmarkdown calls to mathjax. Any one with ideas on how to fix this? As mentioned, there has been problems in the past that was fixed. I wonder if this problem has re-emerged or if it is something that can or should be fixed inside rmarkdown? I reinstalled R and all the packages and dependencies without improvement.